# Android FragmentActivity Not Recognised

Tags: android

In my `Android` Application, the `FragmentActivity` object along with all of the support libraries don't seem to be recognised. I've installed a bunch of stuff from the SDK Manager but it's still not resolving/detecting the objects. What am I missing?

- `minSdkVersion`: 11
- `targetSdkVersion`: 19
- Android Studio Version 0.6.1

[image]

Comment: Have you properly imported the support library v7 with resources? (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: @Shlublu: `FragmentActivity` is from `support-v4`, which is one of the pieces of the Android Support library without resources.

Comment: @Shlublue Yes. It says it's installed.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's right, there was a bias in my question: as I started by importing the support v7 with resources, as an Eclipse project, v4 was automatically imported and shared. So I never had to import the v4 specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Presumably, you are missing the `android-support-v4` portion of the Android Support library being attached to your app.

Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager. That will be in the Extras section, towards the bottom of the screen.

Then, in the `build.gradle` file for your application, you need to add a `compile` directive for `com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0` to your top-level `dependencies` closure, adding it if it is not already there:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Comment: CommonsWare for president. I shall mark this as the answer when it's possible to do so.